# Foldl-like operator for Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

Suppose I have a function of this type:

```
once :: (a, b) -> Parser (a, b)
```

Now, I would like to repeatedly apply this parser (somewhat like using `>>=`) and use its last output to feed it in the next iteration.

Using something like

```
sequence :: (a, b) -> Parser (a, b)
sequence inp = once inp >>= sequence
```

with specifying the initial values for the first parser doesn't work, because it would go on until it inevitably fails. Instead, I would like it to stop when it would fail (somewhat like `many`).

Trying to fix it using `try` makes the computation too complex (adding try in each iteration).

```
sequence :: (a, b) -> Parser (a, b)
sequence inp = try (once inp >>= sequence) <|> pure inp
```

In other words, I am looking for a function somewhat similar to `foldl` on Parsers, which stops when the next Parser would fail.

Comment: How do you define `Parser`?

Comment: it's from Test.Parsec.String: ```type Parser = Parsec String ()```

Comment: OK so it isn't quite clear what the problem with `try` is. *The parser try p behaves like parser p, except that it pretends that it hasn't consumed any input when an error occurs. This combinator is used whenever arbitrary look ahead is needed* If you need this semantic, then `try` seems like the right thing to use. If you don't need any lookahead  (i.e. when the parser fails, it consumes no input), perhaps use `option` instead. If you don't care about it partially consuming input, use a parser with a custom error state and interpret failure as success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `once` parser fails immediately without consuming input, you don't need `try`.  As a concrete example, consider a rather silly `once` parser that uses a pair of delimiters to parse the next pair of delimiters:

```
once :: (Char, Char) -> Parser (Char, Char)
once (c1, c2) = (,) <$ char c1 <*> anyChar <*> anyChar <* char c2
```

You can parse a nested sequence using:

```
onces :: (Char, Char) -> Parser (Char, Char)
onces inp = (once inp >>= onces) <|> pure inp
```

which works fine:

```
> parseTest (onces ('(',')')) "([])[{}]{xy}xabyDONE"
('a','b')
```

You only need `try` if your `once` might fail after parsing input.  For example, the following won't parse without try:

```
> parseTest (onces ('(',')')) "([])[not valid]"
parse error at (line 1, column 8):
unexpected "t"
expecting "]"
```

because we start parsing the opening delimiter `[` before discovering `not valid]`.

(With `try`, it returns the correct `('[',']')`.)

All that being said, I have no idea how you came to the conclusion that using `try` makes the computation "too complex".  If you are just guessing from something you've read about `try` being potentially inefficient, then you've misunderstood.  `try` can cause problems if it's used in a manner than can result in a big cascade of backtracking.  That's not a problem here -- at most, you're backtracking a single `once`, so don't worry about it.